# src/main/BytesMessage.cpp:24:30: fatal error: cms/BytesMessage.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, activemq-classic, activemq-cpp

Can someone tell me how to install pyactivemq?

I was following "Fedora Core" instructions from http://code.google.com/p/pyactivemq/wiki/Building

```
[mmopuru@mmopuru pyactivemq]$ python setup.py build
running build
running build_ext
building 'pyactivemq' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DBOOST_PYTHON_NO_PY_SIGNATURES=1 -DPYACTIVEMQ_ENABLE_DOCSTRINGS=0 
    -I/opt/activemq-cpp-3.0.1/include/activemq-cpp-3.0.1 -I/zyme_shared/zyme_apps/zymenet/dev/python2.6/include/python2.6 -c src/main/BytesMessage.cpp 
    -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/src/main/BytesMessage.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
src/main/BytesMessage.cpp:24:30: fatal error: cms/BytesMessage.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are missing the install of the ActiveMQ-CPP client on your system or the installation is not in a location where the python client build can find the CMS header files.

You should install the ActiveMQ-CPP client and then build the python client.

It's been awhile since I built that python thing.  If I recall correctly the build scripts have some hard coded version numbers in them so you might want to look through the build files and change things to match your system and installed version.

Comment: i did installed "activemq-cpp" as given in https://code.google.com/p/pyactivemq/wiki/Building